# Parse contents of a file between certain timestamps

Tags: linux, bash, sed, awk, grep

I have a log file that contains a lot of information and I would like to only parse the contents of that file which fall within the last 24 hours

Each line in the file begins with a timestamp such as `Jan  31 13:13:02` and then has a log message.

I currently have a batch file that finds the start and end time like this

```
start=$(date +"%b  %d %H:%M:%S" --date="-1 day")
end=$(date +"%b  %d %H:%M:%S")
```

I was then hoping to use these times along with a `grep -c "data_to_find"` to find the number of occurrences of a certain log message so that I can then act on this later.

In short, How can I take into account the times and then grep the content for the number of occurrences of a string within said file?

I am on a linux system and have no issue with any solution that uses SED, AWK, GREP etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not so simple without writing a shell script (especially if it's not sorted).

I would try something like this to get all the lines between 1 day ago and now (interpolate as needed), and then `grep -c` pipe whatever you want from output. Note below assumes date format is something like `Jan  31 13:13:02` (2 spaces between Month and Day)

```
#!/bin/bash
yest=$(date -d "1 days ago" '+%s')
today=$(date '+%s')

while read -r line; do
  date=
  [[ $line =~ ^[[:alpha:]]+[[:blank:]][[:blank:]][0-9]+[[:blank:]][0-9]+':'[0-9]+':'[0-9]+ ]] && date="${BASH_REMATCH[0]}"
  [[ -n $date ]] && date=$(date -d "$date" '+%s')
  [[ -n $date && $date -ge $yest && $date -le $today ]] && echo "$line"
done < logfile
```

Comment: I assume logfile will be replaced with name of file?

Comment: @const_ref Yes. Should work with any logfile of the format you specified "Jan 31 13:13:02" type date strings, followed by whatever message.

Comment: Doesnt seem to work for me, when I execute the script nothing is displayed even though there is stuff in the file. If I remove the stuff in the do and just replace it with an echo of the line the contents are printed as expected

Comment: @const_ref Can you provide a sample of the log file?

Comment: Sorry the error was with my original output, there is a double space between the month and the date which of course will cause this way to fail :(

Comment: @const_ref Ok just replace that part with `[[:blank:]][[:blank:]]`

Answer (score 0):

This can be tricky because the time with the exact second you are looking for may not exist if there was no log entry at that time.

Another possibility may be to add a marker to the log each time you read it and then just look at entries after your last marker. So, when you have read the log, let's say it is called "log.txt" you could do:

```
echo marker >> log.txt
```

Then, when you want to read the log starting from your last marker, you can find the last marker like this:

```
LASTMARKER=$(grep -n marker log.txt | tail -1 | awk -F: '{print $1}')
```

and read everything after it like this:

```
sed -n "$LASTMARKER,$ p" log.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n "/^${start}/,/^${end}/ { /${YourPattern}/ p}" | wc -l
```

Awk could certainly do that in one script. In sed, counting is a bit complex so `wc` is used (a bit faster than `sed -n '$ ='`).
Yourpattern is a regex that suite to your log message to find